# Create an xml file that can open in Excel NO INTEROP OR DLLS

Tags: c#, excel

before you rush and say it's a duplicate please read on.
I am looking for an example xml file that I can use as a template to produce an excel file that can contain spreadsheets inside it.

I cannot use openxml or third party dlls .Only pure c#.

Question.
Do you have a template xml that i can reproduce and create so that can be saved as xslx and be opened as excel file?
Even better do you have some code I can use?

I have found thousands of pages on the internet but none on what the xml structure should be and how to write to xml without any dlls or 3rd party solution.

Yes I need to reinvent the wheel. Can you help?

Comment: Why don't you create an `.xslx` file yourself, using Excel, and look at that as a template?

Comment: Any competent C language level programmer could help. I think the operative question may be closer to **Why?** If you are looking to bypass licensing the the sheer weight of developing this from scratch would outweigh any gains and still leave you liable to intellectual property claims from the XLSX (or XLST) format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand, why can't you use openxml, but anyway. .xlsx file is actually .zip file, containing folders and xml files (You can just rename the .xlsx extension and see it youself). So, first of all, you need to find a way to open and write zip. I don't know do you have restrictions on this matter. I hope not, otherwise you need to reinvent two wheels. Content of the .xlsx is pretty simple, you absolutely can treat it as xml, which it is. And to create first .xlsx you can use Excel (as Mark Seemann said), then extract xml files from it - and that is you template.

Comment: Two wheels, lol -- that's a bike! :D

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I really did not understand the downvoting.Where I work they do not want us to use and external dll.It's not my choice.I will find a way.for now i will accept you as an answer